# regexp search and replace for bash variables

Tags: emacs, regex, bash-scripting, find-and-replace

A number of my bash scripts need tidying up before sending them round. One of the thing I would like to do is to use curly braces for all variable names. So everywhere it says `$PWD` should be changed into `${PWD}` et cetera.

As a test I use the code

```
PATH=${PWD}
PATH_PATH=$PATH
PATH_PATH_PATH=$PATH_PATH
```

My idea was to use regexp search and replace in `emacs`. The best expression that finds all my variable names (with CTRL-ALT-S) is `$[A-Za-z0-9_\-]*`, so a sequence of 'a' through 'z', 'A' through 'Z', '0' through '9', underscore or hyphen following a '$'. Also, it leaves the already-braced variable names alone.

Now replace:
In the manual it says that replace is 'M-% string RET newstring RET'. On my computer 'M-%' is 'ESC-%'. Regexp replace is given as 'C-M-% regexp RET newstring RET'. I guess that would be C-ESC-% for me? Unfortunately, that is also the shortcut for the 'system activity' monitor in KDE.

I'm left with 2 questions now:

1. is there another way to invoke regexp replace than C-ESC-%
2. for the excmple above, what should be the expression for 'newstring'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the regexp `[$]\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\)` and the replacement string `${\1}`.  Here's an explanation for my changes to your regexp:

- The character `$` matches the "end of line" position, so you need to escape it when matching a literal `$`.  Using `[$]` instead of `\$` is a matter of taste (and it cuts down on backslashes that might need to be escaped if you want to translate this to elisp).
- You don't need to backslash-escape `-` inside the character alternative, and indeed you can't; including the backslash just matches backslashes too.  From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special):

  > As a ‘\’ is not special inside a character alternative, it can never
  >   remove the special meaning of ‘-’ or ‘]’.  So you should not quote these
  >   characters when they have no special meaning either.  This would not
  >   clarify anything, since backslashes can legitimately precede these
  >   characters where they *have* special meaning, as in ‘[^\]’ (‘"[^\\]"’
  >   for Lisp string syntax), which matches any single character except a
  >   backslash.

  But `-` will match itself when used inside a character alternative, as long as it can't be interpreted as part of a range.  To be safe, put it first or last.
- I think you don't want to match a lone `$`, so you should use `+` instead of `*`.  Probably not too big a deal, though.
- Finally, you need to wrap the variable name in `\(` `\)` so you can reference it in the replacement string (as `\1`).

As to your second question, you have several options:

- The most straightforward option is `ESC C-%`.  Note that `ESC` isn't a modifier key, it's a prefix key.
- You could use the fact that Emacs interprets `ESC` and `C-[` identically and use `C-[ C-%`.
- You could invoke the command by name as `M-x query-replace-regexp`.
- Or you could bind the command to a more convenient key in your personal configuration.

Comment: Thanks - that is fantastic! I found the regexp search documentation, but your `${\1}` for replacing was missing - just what I needed. Also thanks for improving the regexp - I escaped the hyphen by default as it is used for ranges (like 'A-Z') so: interpreted. Very powerful stuff